# Is there any tool to watch session variables currently available in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jetty

Using Tomcat or Jetty, I am wondering from server side, is there any tools/method to inspect session varibles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides runtime debugging and printing out such values I'm not aware of such a method.

AFAIK there was a possibility in early java versions that was wiped out for security reasons.